# How do i rewrite Django function based views code in a class based view?

Tags: python-3.x, django, function, class, django-views

i have the following code for a function based view:

```
fav = bool
if post.favourites.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    fav=True
```

but i want to put that in the below class based view:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['productobj'] = Post.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['pk'])
    return context
```

i am fairly new to Django, so i don't know all that much about functions inside class based views and how to pass parameters from them. can anyone help to add the code to the above class based view and pass "fav" to a context dictionary.

Comment: Share your entire function based view.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `get_context_data` you can use the self. before the request. So...

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['productobj'] = Post.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
    return context
```